# android | multiple onclicklistener in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, onclicklistener

Inside my Activity I start a simple dialog.

```
final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.testing);
...
```

My testing.xml Layout consists of nothing but 10 ImageViews, id`s are '1' to '10'.

I want every ImageView to be clickable and to do something.
The define the onclick() methode in the .xml file isn`t working, as the methode can't be found when the dialog is viewed.

The only way I got it work is following: define 10 onclick-listeners:

```
ImageView img_1 = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.1);
ImageView img_2 = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.2);
...

img_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  execute_funtion(1);
  myDialog.cancel();
}
});

img_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  execute_funtion(2);
  myDialog.cancel();
}
});

...
```

However, that's really bad code, I have 10 times nearly the same lines.

So my question: How can I make that work with clean code?
I thought about a multiple onclicklistener (overwride the onClick() function and make a switch/case in the functions or something like that), but it's not working.

I'm happy about every idea!
Thanks

/EDIT

Here a snippet of the .xml file

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="2dp"
  android:onClick="myFunction"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: what do you mean **define the onclick() methode in the .xml** .  post that .xml file as well

Comment: i added it, thanks for calling attention!
When clicking the image, "myFunction()" can't be found.

Comment: Use switch case as you have mentioned `overwride the onClick() function and make a switch/case in the functions or something like that`. But first rename your ids. It is not allowed numerical id, use img1, img2 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your Activity implement `OnClickListener` and then process the `onClick` event like below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.img1:
        ...
        break;
    case R.id.img2:
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you can't define id as number.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should let your `Activity`/`Fragment` implement the `OnClickListener`.
2. When you do that you will have to override the `onClick` method in that particular activity/fragment.
3. Set the `onClickListener`s on the images as follows:

   ```
   img_1.setOnClickListener(YourActivity.this);
   ```
4. Then in that `onClick` method you can put a switch case or an if else if case as follows

   ```
   @Override  
   public void onClick(View v)
   {   
       if(v==img_1) {  
             //do this  
       } else if(v==img_2) {  
           //do that  
       }...  
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case img_1.getId(): // do this
               break;
           case img_2.getId(): // do that
               break;
           .
           .
           .
           default : break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry, the first piece of code is not formatting for some reason!

Comment: "case img_1.getId():" isn't working, but it works when i write
  "case R.id.1"

thanks!