# Android method paramater variable meaning/use?

Tags: android, methods, parameters

beginner here.

First off, this question arrived while i was trying to implement button clicks using android:onClick in xml and referencing a method.

Now, when you reference a method, the parameter of the method in the activity must be "(View)". Quick question, what is the variable after the word View in the method parameter? Usually it's like "(View v)" or "(View view)". What is the second variable in the parameter, can it be anything? When is it used? Just want general info about it, couldn't really find such specific info anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are not two arguments.  Every argument must be declared with a name and a type.  `View v` declares an argument called `v` of type`View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood. The first parameter in `(View view)` is the type of the parameter, and the second is the temporary name supplied to it (it is just a dummy name, so you can use whatever you like). For example, if I have to pass an integer as parameter, I would use `(int i)`, where `i` is understood to be of type `int`. So, in your case an object of type `View` is temporarily called `view` to be passed as parameter into a function.

Comment: So whatever is after View in this case, i could change to whatever i like? Kinda like a variable?

Comment: Yes, which is why it is also called a "dummy" variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is reference to the view you are clicking. Take a look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505105/android-multiple-onclicklistener-in-dialog/16505164#16505164) here, and you may find when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking about `onClick()`?
This method is from `View.onClickListener` interface, you can see the document in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Because it is an interface, so there will be only paramater :View, it represents the view you just clicked. for example, if you set a button into the interface, it means button, if you set a ImageView into the interface, it means the ImageView itself;

For example:

```
YourActiivty extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
     public void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstance) {
         super.onCreate(onSaveInstance);

         setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
         //your button, we assume id is R.id.yourbutton;
         Button yourbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
         yourbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
         //your imageview, we assume id is R.id.yourimageview;
         ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageview);
         yourImageView.setClickable(true);
         yourImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          int id = v.getId();
          if(id == R.id.yourbutton) {
             //your button is clicked!
          } else if(id == R.id.yourimageview) {
             //your imageview is clicked!
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to ask what the actual letter "v" is after the parameter View. Is that just something like a variable, i could change it to whatever i want?

Comment: Of course you can change it to whatever you want. I think it should be some basic knowledge about Programming.

Comment: Very basic. Which is why i'm a begginer :)